# Best node ORM module for high load application

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm

I'm developing a node.js app that will have a very high load (thousands of requests per second) and I want the advice of someone experienced with high load node.js apps and ORM modules.

I use `node-orm2` for smaller projects but I don't know if that's the right choice in this case.

The app will demand thousands of database reads/writes per second and I want to use an ORM module that provides the best performance possible, at any service load.

I will use PostgreSQL as database.

Comment: I don't know about performance but [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) is one of the most used ORM in nodejs environment. You could do a benchmark.

Comment: ORM-s are typically slow. If you want top performance, don't use any. You need a framework that can be easily optimized for high performance, while also easy to use, like [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: @vitaly-t I can see you're the creator of pg-promise. What would that optimizations be?

Comment: @karuzo for starters, this: [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost) - one of the most crucial optimizations that you won't even be able to do with ORM-s, - reducing IO interactions, so necessary to handle very high loads.

Comment: @vitaly-t So, if I understand your article, I need to basically join queries when possible and avoid using unnecessary ones. Is that right?

Comment: @karuzo essentially, yes, though perhaps not everywhere, rather in places where high volume of data is expected, or high-intensity requests. We can chat here, if you want: https://gitter.im/vitaly-t/pg-promise?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that using orm in high load it's a good idea.

Recently, I try several different orms and databases on high load node project and came to the conclusion that the best way it's using something like Redis and npm modul like ioredis.

As an option, you can use different data bases for regular and high load operation. For example, PostgreSQL with sequelize for regular operation and some NoSQL like Redis for high load.

And, if it's possible, try to cache results or avoid dada base requests as much as possible.

If you find another solution, please let me know, because it's a realy important question for me.